# Gnome install on gentoo: "gnome-session not found"

Tags: linux, gnome, gentoo

I am trying to install gentoo on an old desktop I have. I have not used gentoo before, and have run into some problems getting gnome to work 
Following the gnome install guide on the wiki (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GNOME/Guide), calling 'startx' as a user gives the error: 
`/home/sam/.xinitrc: line 2: exec: gnome-session: not found`

My ~/.xinitrc looks like:

```
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome- 
exec gnome-session
```

It seems to me that the command gnome-session should be installed but is not... `which gnome-session` gives me:

```
which: no gnome-session in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3:/usr/games/bin)
```

I ran `emerge --searchdesc gnome-session` and found the package "gnome-base/gnome-session". Installing this package using `emerge --ask gnome-base/gnome-session` did not fix the problem. I am a newbie to gentoo and linux in general so any advise is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in emerging gnome-session... turns out I had not set up my swap correctly and it was running out of memory. All good now!